# How to solve json response from Vue to rasa custom action

Tags: vue.js, chatbot, rasa-nlu

Ok, so everything works out fine in during rasa shell but when connecting it to the frontend (Vuejs), it keeps giving the error message that i set up when the rasa action server fails to responds. i think it might be the json response part from Vue to rasa action server since it provided this response in the console:
`Response received: {message: 'Sorry, something went wrong.'}`

this is my frontend:

```
  methods: {
    sendMessage() {
      console.log('sendMessage method started');
      axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/webhook', {
        sender:'user',
        message: this.userMessage
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Response received:', response.data);
        const botResponse = response.data; // Access the full JSON response

        // Construct the displayed response with additional fields
        let displayedResponse = botResponse.message;
        if (botResponse.syn) {
          displayedResponse += "\nSynonyms: ${botResponse.syn}"
        }
        if (botResponse.exp) {
          displayedResponse += "\nExplanation: ${botResponse.exp}"
        }
        if (botResponse.ant) {
          displayedResponse += "\nAntonyms: ${botResponse.ant}";
        }

        // Update the UI with the displayed response
        this.messages.push({ content: this.userMessage, sender: 'user' });
        this.messages.push({ content: displayedResponse, sender: 'bot' });
        this.userMessage = '';
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
      })
      .finally(()=>{
        console.log('sendMessage method completed');
      })
    },
  },
```

this is my backend:

```
def webhook():
    data = request.get_json()   
    # Forward the incoming message to Rasa server
    rasa_response = requests.post('http://localhost:5055/webhook', json=data)
    if rasa_response.status_code == 200:
        rasa_data = rasa_response.json()
        if rasa_data:
            reply_text = rasa_data[0].get('text', 'Sorry, I didn\'t understand.')
            input_text = rasa_data[0].get('input')
            synonyms = rasa_data[0].get('syn')
            explanation = rasa_data[0].get('exp')
            antonyms = rasa_data[0].get('ant')
            return jsonify({
                'message': reply_text,
                'input': input_text,
                'syn': synonyms,
                'exp': explanation,
                'ant': antonyms
            })
    return jsonify({'message': 'Sorry, something went wrong.'})
```

this is some of my rasa custom action:

```
class MalayaExpAction(Action):
  
  def name(self) -> Text:
    return "ms_explanation_action"
  
  def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher, tracker: Tracker, dialogue) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:
    user_input=tracker.get_latest_input_channel()
    
    try:
      model = malaya.summarization.abstractive.huggingface(model = 'mesolitica/finetune-summarization-ms-t5-small-standard-bahasa-cased')
      summary = model.generate([user_input],do_sample=True,max_length=256,top_p=0.92,top_k=0,num_return_sequences=3,threshold = 0.0)
      dispatcher.utter_message(response="utter_ms_explanation_action",exp=f"{summary}")
      return []
    
    except Exception as e:
      dispatcher.utter_message(f"An Error Occured: {e}")
      return []
```

```
class SpacyAntAction(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "en_antonym_action"

    def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher, tracker: Tracker, domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Text]:
        user_input=tracker.get_latest_input_channel()
        explanation, synonyms, antonyms = self.analyze_text(user_input.text)
        dispatcher.utter_message(response="utter_en_antonym_action",text=user_input,ant=f"Antonyms: {', '.join(antonyms)}")
        return []

    def analyze_text(self, text: Text) -> Tuple[Text, List[Text], List[Text]]:
        nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
        doc = nlp(text)

        # Sentence segmentation
        sent = list(doc.sents)[0]

        # Coreference resolution
        clusters = list(doc._.coref_clusters)

        # Contextualized word embeddings
        word_vectors = nlp.vocab.vectors

        # Explanation
        explanation = ""
        for token in sent:
            if token.pos_ == "NOUN":
                explanation += f"{token.text} is the {token._.dep_} of {token.head.text}"
                # Identify related entities
                for cluster in clusters:
                    if token in cluster:
                        for co_ref in cluster:
                            if co_ref != token:
                                explanation += f"It is also referred to as {co_ref.text}."
                                break
                # Analyze sentiment
                if token._.sentiment != 0:
                    sentiment = "positive" if token._.sentiment > 0 else "negative"
                    explanation += f" It has a {sentiment} sentiment."
                break

        # Synonyms and antonyms
        synonyms = []
        antonyms = []
        for token in sent:
            if token.pos_ == "NOUN":
                # Use contextualized word vectors
                similar_words = nlp(token.text).vector._.most_similar(n=5, vectors=word_vectors)
                for word, sim in similar_words:
                    if token.head != doc[word]: 
                        synonyms.append(word)
                for word, sim in similar_words:
                    if token.head != doc[word]:
                        antonyms.append(word)

        return explanation, synonyms, antonyms
```

, i have tried a lot of ways through youtube and other blogs and reached a deadend which are the code above and error below, it produced this error that originates from the rasa custom action server that i ran using `rasa run action`:

```
Registered function for 'en_antonym_action'.
Registered function for 'en_explanation_action'.
Registered function for 'en_synoynm_action'.
Registered function for 'en_translation_action'.
Registered function for 'ms_antonym_action'.
Registered function for 'ms_explanation_action'.
Registered function for 'ms_synonym_action'.
Registered function for 'ms_translation_action'.
Starting plugins...
Action endpoint is up and running on http://0.0.0.0:5055
Received an action call without an action.
```

Side Notes: `rasa run --enable-api` produced no problem, it runs the server and just does nothing. Also my custom actions code is in their own file like en_antonym.py and is within the actions folder which is in the same level as the actions.py file

Comment: maybe your backend is not directly 127.0.0.1. you can try deploy your rasa app on 127.0.0.1:5055 or try to request axios.post("http: //localhost:5000/webhook") from vuejs

Comment: Ahh, thanks for that, @HoàngNguyễn, i just realized i connected to the rasa action server instead of the rasa server itself, now it works. Instead of http://localhost:5055/webhook in the flask backend, it is http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook